# flutter, how to copy file from directory to a different directory (Android)

Tags: android, flutter

I have a PDF file in this directory "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.test/files/myDownload.pdf", so I want to copy or move it to a new directory such as "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.test/files/newFolder/newName.pdf"
but I'm stuck in this errors

`Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.test/files/newFolder/newName.pdf', path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.test/files/myDownload.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

the code that I'm using to do that is

`final _externalDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();                                          var dir = Directory(_externalDirectory.path);                                                              String path = _externalDirectory.path + '/' + newPath;                                                     getfileX().copy(path);`

Comment: That is incomplete code. Please post reproducable code in ONE codeblock. The path you use has nothing to do with the paths mentioned in your text. Further you should use File.exists() before you try to copy a file.

Comment: yes ,this folder '/newFolder ' is dont existe how can I make a new one ?

Comment: What yes? What?

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your interest I have solved the issue